# Scan a file, get path and create directory from path

Tags: bash, mkdir

I have concocted the following small script to read a file, extract a search path on disk and use mkdir to create it, now for some reason on all directories it creates it has a trailing ? march character or possibly a /w

What have I done wrong?

```
#! /bin/bash
echo "which file do you want to scan: "
read input 
file=`echo $input | tr -d '[:space:]' | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]'` 
#echo $file

while IFS= read -r  line; do
    a="$(cut -d'=' -f2 <<<"$line")"
    if [[ "$a" =~ /opt.* ]]; then
        echo $a
        mkdir -p $a
    fi
done < "$file"
```

Result from the script looks like this:

```
/opt/dir/foo01/arch:
aggr_rec?  aggr_rec_tag?  input?  input_tag?
```

and the `?` marks should not be there

Comment: Can you provide the content from your file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely your input file contains DOS line endings `\r\n`. Example:

```
$ mkdir -p /tmp/dos/file$'\r'
$ ls /tmp/dos
file?
```

Use `dos2unix` on the input file.

But you can replace the whole while loop with one `sed`:

```
#! /bin/bash

sed -n -e 's/^[^=]*=\(\/opt[^=]*\).*$/\1/p' <<EOF |
a=/tmp/1
b=/opt/2
c=/tmp/3
d=/opt/4
EOF
xargs -n1 echo mkdir
```

Remove the `echo` to create the directories.

The `sed` option `-n` tells `sed` to generate output only for successful replacements by `s`. This does the `/opt` prefix filtering.

The `xargs` option `-n` tells `xargs` to use just one argument, but this is optional, because `mkdir` can create more than one directory at once.